How to fix distorted image on a plane with double face?
Basically, I'm making an animation of a book whose pages turn/leaf. I made the pages with a minimum thickness so as to have double sides and in this way to be able to use an image for each side of the page. With this page it gives me this error: that is, the image is distorted and even modifying in UV/shading, the problem persists. I made 2 more pages and I didn't have this problem.
In the attached image you can see the nodes when I select a page. I'm not an expert, I just copied a tutorial online.
Blender Project File


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Looking at your image it doesn't seem like you have any texture set in the ImageTexture node using the UVMap.001 channel.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Distortion is caused by bad UV Unwrapping:
select the distorted page, go to edit mode (TAB key), select the big face that should hold the drawing and press U (Unwrap).
Then in the UV editing workspace press R, 180, Enter, to rotate the UV.
Repeat for the UVMap.001.


Wow, I solved it! Thank you so much @josh
